# Writing a generic CRUD method that works regardless of type

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite-net

I have an SQLite database and 5 classes/data-types (for this example I'm only going to use two of them: *expense* and *category*) and a *DatabaseService* that takes care of adding, deleting, updating and getting data from the database. It looks like this:

```
public class Expense
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Indexed]
    public int CategoryId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Amount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class Category
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Color
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int TotalSpent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class DatabaseService
{
    static SQLiteAsyncConnection db;
    static async Task Init()
    {
        if (db != null) return;
        var databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "db.db3");
        db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);
        await db.CreateTableAsync < Expense > ();
        await db.CreateTableAsync < Category > ();
    }
    public async Task < int > AddEntryAsync(object entry)
    {
        return await db.InsertAsync(entry);
    }
    public async Task < int > RemoveEntryAsync(int id)
    {
        return await db.DeleteAsync < object > (id);
    }
    public async Task < IEnumerable < object >> GetEntriesAsync()
    {
        return await db.Table < object > ().ToListAsync();
    }
    public async Task < int > UpdateEntryAsync(object entry)
    {
        return await db.UpdateAsync(entry);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is write *generic* Add, Delete, Get and Update methods that work regardless of the type, mostly because I think that writing the same 4 methods 5 times over is not an ideal solution. Is there any way to do this, or do I just give up and copy-paste the methods five times?

I'm using Sqlite-net-pcl (1.8.116) on .net maui preview.

Comment: So the closest thing I think you are trying to do is the _repo pattern (RP)_, a pattern tries to avoid duplication in code when dealing with databases.  However the RP is best served for non-CRUD operations and even then for _retrieving data_ when the LINQ query is somewhat reasonably complex (the code you don't want duplicated).  Your class seems to be adding an abstraction layer around the DB API encapsulating the nitty gritty which is a good start however the actual operations presented I don't think are that useful.

Comment: ...you might want to consider making `DatabaseService` a generic like `DatabaseService<T>` so that calls to `public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetEntriesAsync()` are _type safe_.

Comment: @MickyD i tried that but i was getting a "Class Mapping Error: 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor", so i did what someone suggested on another question and defined the class like this: `public class DatabaseService<T> where T : new()` . is that a good solution? i have no idea of what `where T : new()`  means

Comment: So what that's saying is the type you pass into `DatabaseService<T>`, let's say `MissPiggy`, the type `MissPiggy` must have a constructor like this:  `public MissPiggy() { }`.  Don't make it `private` or `internal` and this particular constructor must not take any parameters.  You can define other constructors if you like but you must at least define a parameter-less one that is public.

Comment: @MickyD oh, that's good, it'll work fine with my data-types. Thanks for the help :p